# Use permanent or temporary willpower for gifts?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse

In **Werewolf the Apocalypse, 20th Anniversary edition**, there is a gift called Jam Weapon. It states:

> The Garou shouts an ancient word of power and grace and spends a Gnosis point. The player rolls Willpower against a difficulty of highest Willpower of any armed individual within earshot.

Is the player's dice pool based on their current or total willpower?
Is the difficulty based on current willpower or total willpower of the enemy?

Current being remaining temporary willpower points and total being the number of dots in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't the references in front of me at the moment, but when you *check* your Willpower stat to determine how many dice to roll, you always check your actual (total) Willpower, not your current Willpower point pool.  Likewise, when you *spend* Willpower, you always spend temporary Willpower points, not permanent Willpower rating.

There are exceptions, I can think of at least one Vampire Discipline that spends permanent Willpower, lowering your stat until repurchased with experience, but those are rather rare.  As a general rule, if you need your Willpower stat (when *checking* or *rolling* Willpower), you use your permanent dots;  if you're spending your Willpower resource (*losing* or *spending* Willpower), you're using the points marked in the boxes.

Comment: For 1st through Revised Editions of many WoD games this was true.  In Vampire 20th, many of the powers started checking against the target's temporary Willpower points, to make depleting that matter more.  Some W20 was written after V20, it might use the same rule.  Worth looking (Sorry, I don't have a copy).

Answer (score 3):

A search reveals that, in contrast to **Vampire**, the phrase "Current Willpower" appears nowhere in **Werewolf 20th Anniversary**. It's reasonable to conclude that the rule hasn't changed between editions, and the target number is therefore the highest permanent Willpower of any applicable individual. V20 appears to be an outlier; we'll have to see what M20 and Wr20 do to figure out if there's a pattern.